# Добавить свой meta тег через controller, kohana framework

Tags: kohana, kohana-3

Необходимо добавить теги в проект, к примеру rel= «canonical» и многие другие. Для каждого контроллера теги и значение тега будут разными. Есть возможно зарегистрировать(добавить) тег через controller и как это можно сделать?

Версия фреймворка: 3.1.3.1

Answer (score 0):

Отвечу на свой же вопрос. Вариант, который нашел я, следующий. 
В контролере создаем переменную, записываем нужную информацию. 
Дальше выводим нужную нам информацию с помощью $this->document. 
Я выводил в layout, получилось так: $this->document->your_variable = $your_variable в контроллера, и $document->your_variable в layout